# Which metric to use to evaluate prediction problem

Tags: python, machine-learning-model

The product manager wants to know if you can develop a model to predict the number of
views a listing will receive based on the boat's features. **She would consider using your model if, on average, the predictions were only 50% off of the true number of views a listing would
receive.**

(please interpret the bold sentence!!)

The data used in this: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/karthikbhandary2/boat-sales

I tried using the RandomForestRegressor() model along with RandomizedSearchCV.

```
param = [
    {'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000], 
     'max_depth': [3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12,14,16,18,20], 
     'max_leaf_nodes': [15, 20, 25,30,35,40]}, 
]

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
rs_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, param, cv = 4, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 1)
rs_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I tried using RMSE like this:

```
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print(rmse)
```

I got the result as 483887.72666891955

My question is whether I am doing this right or not?

Comment: If you want to see how much the prediction is off from the actual value as a percentage you should look into using the mean average percentage error (MAPE).

Comment: How can I do that? So RMSE is not the metric to use?

Comment: If you are mainly interested in the model's error as a percentage of the actual value then no.

Comment: So I should go with MAPE? And How can I implement it? Can you submit it as an answer??

Comment: Now it is returning 1.2265745506841434, after using the mean_average_percentage_error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how much the prediction is off from the actual value as a percentage you should look into using the mean average percentage error (MAPE). The `scikit-learn` library has this loss implemented in the `metrics` package. You can simply call the [`mean_absolute_percentage_error` function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html) instead of the `mean_squared_error` you're currently using:

```
mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Now it is returning 1.2265745506841434, after using the mean_average_percentage_error.

Comment: So how can I interpret 1.2265 as? Is it 1% or what? Can you tell me @Oxbowerce

Comment: A value of 1.2265 means that on average, your model's predictings are off by 122.65% from the actual values the model is trying to predict.

Comment: Can you give me some advice on how to improve it?

Comment: Not really, as this is really dependent on the type of problem you are working on. In general, try to really understand the data you're working with, see what features are correlated with what you're trying to predict, and see if feature engineering can help create more meaningful features for your model to use.

Comment: ok, I understand!!